# How to set a textView width dynamically larger than the width of the screen after animation?

Tags: android, animation

I have a text view with a height which wraps content and a width that matches parent. So that the textView width == the screen Width.
But at one point I want the text to rotate 90 degrees.
Now I want to be able to change the views width so that it is the devices height instead of width. 
This would cause that the width would expand.
(Basically like when one does orientation changes, but I can´t just have an orientation change for only one textview so I have to rotate it.)

My problem: I can´t set the textViews width larger than the device width.
Even when I am already done with the animation.

So is it possible to make the textView width larger than the device width?
and if not can anyone please suggest how I could solve my problem because I really need to change the orientation of the textView...

EDIT----EDIT

Is there a way to create a landscape text view and put it in a portait activity? That would completly solve my problems of the last week...

EDIT

My fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/f"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/t"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried different things like

```
fragment.setRotation(90);
  LayoutParams params = fragment.getLayoutParams();
                params.height = text.getHeight();
                params.width = deviceHeight;
                fragment.setLayoutParams(params);

 LayoutParams params1 = text.getLayoutParams();
                params1.height = text.getHeight();
                params1.width = deviceHeight;
                text.setLayoutParams(params1);
```

EDIT________EDIT

Or has anyone ever written something like a verticalTExtView Class?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the attributes of `TextView` as `android:singleLine="true"` and `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content" // incase if you do not want the height to be increashed` so `singleLine` is making the text to go out of screen width then you will need `ScrollView` for such behavior.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply... I don´t really want the text to be displayed in one line. It is possible that I put html formatted text in it

Comment: Yes, you can also insert `html` in `TextView` as well. You will use then `TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("your html strin"))`

Comment: Yes, but than the text is being displayed in one line, I checked that. I don´t want the text to be in one line

Comment: Remove singleLine = true if you wrote that

Comment: That doesn´t change anything I think... or I don´t really understand what your suggestion is.

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: I want my text view rotated by 90 degrees so that it is vertical. than I want the width ot match the decice so that it goes over the full device.(device height since it has been rotated) this sould cause the text to fromat new so that since now the width is larger the hight gets less.

Comment: What I have understood is that you want the text width to increase to screen width and when screen goes to landscape then textview should adjust its width accordingly. right?